How can i fix this can't find module error?
I followed a bcsfe tutorial correctly but when i did step 11, entering python -m bcsfe comes out with No module named bcsfe despite being exactly what the tutorial says to do. how do i fix this?

The only tag on this question is drivers which is for Linux kernel modules. Whereas the question is about a Python module. Can the question be edited to explain how it related to Ubuntu.

ah ok got it. i meant to make a modules tag ok? thx if you can help
